# How do I stop the 'Information Regarding Web Browsers' window from appearing everytime I log in?

Tags: browser

Everytime I log in I see the 'Information Regarding Web Browsers' browser choice popup. Even if I click OK and then select the browser that I already have installed it still appears next time I log in.

How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete "browserchoice.exe" from:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32
```

Answer (score -2):

I tried to do this but it said only 'TrustedInstaller' had permission to delete it. So I found further information on a Microsoft forum, about allowing you to delete it:

Copied from [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/removing-browserchoiceexe/99e8fd47-67bd-4952-94c7-8bd6cf75b6d9):

> You can remove the file, but under Windows 7 (and presumably Vista)
>   you cannot delete the browserchoice.exe file from the system32
>   directory, as you get an error saying that you need permission from
>   TrustedInstaller to delete or change this file.   To resolve this you
>   need to go to the file properties (select browserchoice.exe, right
>   click and click on properties). Next select the Security tab. At this
>   point you will notice that Microsoft have installed a user group
>   called TrustedInstaller, which has full permission to delete the file,
>   whereas Admins and users do not. The next step is to click on the
>   Advanced button and then select the Owner tab. Change the Owner to
>   yourself and click Apply. Close that window and go back to the
>   security tab. THe final step is to select your user and then give
>   yourself Full control of the file. You will now be able to delete the
>   offending article from your computer.